# Tensorflow 2.3 / Keras - Gradient Function for a custom upsampling layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, backpropagation

I wrote a function that makes upsampling in a different way from what does Upsampling2D. I wrapped this function in `tf.py_function` and I wrapped that in a Lambda layer to avoid `ValueError: Unknown graph. Aborting.` .
However py_function needs a gradient function to work because it returns None in backpropagation.

`Invalid argument:  Inputs to operation gradient_tape/SegNet/activation_23/ReluGrad of type ReluGrad must have the same size and shape. Input 0: [] != input 1: [16,16,32,32]`

```
conv_24 = Activation("relu")(conv_24)
unpool_5 = Lambda(unpoolWrapper)(conv_24)
unpool_5 = Lambda(adjustShape, arguments={'oldshape': conv_24.shape})(unpool_5)
conv_25 = Conv2D(16, (5,5),kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same',
data_format='channels_first')(unpool_5)
```

Problem is inside the first Lambda.

```
def unpoolWrapper(tensor):
    return py_func(unpool, [tensor], Tout=tf.float32)
```

I'm following this [code](https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342#file-tensorflow_py_func_with_grad-py) to fix the gradient problem.
However I'm inexpert so I don't know how gradient is computed for this kind of layer. It just makes an upsampling operation, no parameters to learn. Can anybody suggest me a gradient function for this? Thanks

```
def py_func(func, inp, Tout,grad=None):
    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)  # see _MySquareGrad for grad example
    g = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_function(func, inp, Tout)
```